# Download a PDF retrieved by an API in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pdf, download

ok, so, i've an API that send me a string($binary), that's an example:

```
%PDF-1.7
%����
6 0 obj
<</Length 5 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode/N 3/Range[0 1 0 1 0 1 ]>>
stream
x���wTS��Ͻ7�P����khRH
�H�.*1  J�� etc...
```

the API send me this PDF file as a string(it sends me the PDF source) and i need to make it a file in JS to make it downloadable by the user

the API is protected with an Auth and that's the only thing he respond, i'm working on Laravel, i've tried to make it a blob and a cuple other things, i attach a sample code of the last try i made:

```
function downloadVisura(){
            axios.get('https://catasto.openapi.it/visura_catastale/' + "{{$visura->id_visura}}" + '/documento', {
                headers: {
                    'accept': 'application/pdf',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer [Token_Censored]'
                }
                })
                .then ( (res) => {

                    data = res.data;

                    console.log(data);

                    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.download = "visura.pdf";
                    link.click();


                })
        }
```

if i try to download it like this i receive a file of 130kb corrupted, but if i try to download it with curl --output i recieve a file of 76kb working.

here the docs of the API service if you want to check: https://developers.openapi.it/services/catasto#/Visura%20Catastale/get_visura_catastale__id__documento

i have no other ideas, if you need any other information ask.

Comment: Why are you making a request to an API that requires a token, in client-side code to begin with? (Where every user of the site will be able to _see_ the token.)

Comment: just a test to see if i can download the file, token will not be visible by the user in release